# How to debug remote node.js app using chrome devtools

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools

I have a simple console node.js app that is running on a remote server. I would like to debug it remotely using the Chrome DevTools. How can I do that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Follow this instruction [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/#enabling-remote-debugging-scenarios)
Another good article [here](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/debugging-node-js-with-google-chrome-4965b5f910f4)

Let's say you are running Node on remote machine, remote.example.com, that you want to be able to debug. On that machine, you should start the node process with the inspector listening only to localhost (the default).

> `$ node --inspect server.js`

Now, on your local machine from where you want to initiate a debug client connection, you can setup an ssh tunnel:

> `$ ssh -L 9221:localhost:9229 user@remote.example.com`

Then on your local machine in the Chrome browser go to [this](http://chrome://inspect/#devices) address:

> chrome://inspect/#devices

You should see something like this:

[image]

Once you click `inspect` you should see the familiar Chrome developers tool window. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Please note, you may have to first click the `Configure` button, and add `localhost:9221` to the `Target Discovery Settings`.

Comment: how can i do this without SSL ?

Comment: Do you mean SSH?

Comment: I use this without SSH on a LAN with `node --inspect=0.0.0.0 server.js`. The configure step above is critical.

Comment: Also, there is `--inspect-brk` option in node command line. It will prevent script from starting , so you may start it after debugger connected

Answer (score 6):

## With Windows Client:

on remote server:

> $ node --inspect server.js

On your local use [Putty](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html) to create ssh tunel.

> [image: Connection -> SSh -> Tunnels]

Click On Add botton:

> [image: After Add button]

On session tab Click to save!

> [image]

And Click on Open.

You can check Tunnel is open with the following command:

> netstat -a -n | grep 9221

On Your local open Chrome navigate to:

> chrome://inspect/#devices

Comment: I had to do one change: I had to specify 'local' instead of 'remote' in the PuTTy tunnerl config. Then it worked like a charm.

Comment: In my environement, Chrome would not reliably start the debugging session. So I switched to Visual Studio Code instead and the debugger opens instantly. See my answer on this page.

Answer (score 3):

There are security considerations, but the following can be an easy/safe solution if on the same network:

On server, launch your app:

`node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 server.js`

Rather than having node bind strictly to localhost, you can have it bind to any network interface via `0.0.0.0:9229`.

Now on your PC, open chrome and goto `chrome://inspect/#devices` . Chrome has changed the UI accouple times but you should be able to configure your remote server IP as a target. E.g. `[server_ip]:9229`. Note, this would be safest to use on a local network where `server_ip` is a local IP address. If you are debugging against a public IP address there would be a risk of someone else attaching.

Answer (score 1):

**With Windows Client and Visual Studio Code**

Here's a variation of Peter's answer, using Visual Studio Code instead of Chrome.

1. Apply all steps from @Peter's answer to setup port forwarding in Putty (be sure to change `remote` to `local` as pointed out in the first comment to @Peter's answer).
2. In Visual Studio Code, add the following configuration:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Remote",
            "address": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": 9221,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/npm",
            "remoteRoot": "/abs/path/npm",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ]
        },
     ]
}
```

3. Use `inpect-brk` to pause your program until the Visual Studio Code has connected to the remote host:

```
node --inspect-brk your-node-program.js
```

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the steps

```
1)Run the application in remote
2)Open application in chrome
3)Open Developer Tools--->Sources
4)Ctrl + p
5)Open file you want to debug  there<filename.js>
6)Place debug points in your now opened file.
```