# Accessing javascript functions on running Node application

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to setup a new node application server and I'm finding it frustrating to debug on. Previously I have mainly worked on web based applications/ chrome extensions and I could easily execute javascript functions, api's and access variables from chrome dev tools.

I have tried --inspect and --inspect-brk coupled with Visual Studio Code and also mapping to chrome://inspect/#devices but to no avail; to make matters worse my node code is remote. Can anyone provide any pointers?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242557/how-to-debug-remote-node-js-app-using-chrome-devtools

Comment: "Pointers" is too broad.  What **exactly** is the issue that you are having using the debugging tools?  The V8 debugging tools should feel very similar to debugging within a browser.

Comment: Did you initiate an ssh tunnel on your local machine? `ssh -L 9221:localhost:9229 user@remote.example.com`

Comment: I have tried the SSH command above, can attach chrome, see my index.js but in console I can't access a variable or function; should I be able to? Thanks