# Remote debug node.js app, Chrome DevTools inspected device is missing

Tags: node.js, remote-debugging

**Steps to reproduce:**

**1.** I running node.js (node@12.14.0) application on remote server (Ubuntu) with

```
> node --inspect app.js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789
```

**2.** On local (Windows 10) configured the SSH tunnel

[image]

[image]

[image]

On click "open" I see, where I input my password

```
Using username "user".
user@site.com's password:
_
```

**3.** Configured the Chrome (URI chrome://inspect/#devices) target discovery settings

[image]

**4.** Finally I see no devices on Remote Target

[image]

But expecting something like this

[image]

**5.** netstat -a -n | grep 9221 on the server returns

[image]

**What I doing wrong?** How do I get the target?

Similar topics:
1. [How to debug remote node.js app using chrome devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242557/how-to-debug-remote-node-js-app-using-chrome-devtools)
2.

Answer (score 2):

In `Discover network target` add `127.0.0.1:9229` instead of the `localhost:9229`

Comment: Thanks this solved my issue immediatelly.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me

**P.1** Run node.js app with root user

```
> node --inspect-brk app.js
```

**P.2** For tunneling used Windows PowerShell with following line

```
ssh -N -L 9221:localhost:9229 root@site.com
```